# Ruby Compass compiler output

Tags: java, compass-sass

I am using java process to execute compass compiler task.
So I am using process.getErrorStream() and process.getInputStream().

In output logs I have strange bash characters like [33m, [31m.
Logs:

2013-02-08 14:03:49,417 INFO  [....BaseProcessManager] (ajp-0.0.0.0-8009-1) Error reader: [31m[0m

Do you know why this happening and if there is solution not to have this symbols in output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are control characters for color log output

their generation is controlled by the `Compass.configuration.color_output`  flag

try running  `compass --boring`  which should remove them for you, or set the color_output flag to false if you want it to be the default.

Comment: Thanks, broth. You saved me a day.